# How do I not lose code when merge between two branches?

Tags: git

The situation is thus, our team has branch dev which we split off of to work on various issues. Sometimes this requires us to be working on the same file but in different branches.

```
user1(file1.txt)   X
                  / \
dev(file1.txt) - A - B - C
                  \       \  
user2(file1.txt)   A' ---- B'
```

The problem is that when we merge user2(B') into dev(C) it tends to override any changes made in commits B C, the same thing happens if we try to merge C into B' first and then merge user2 back into dev.

For example, if in dev(B) I added the line 'this is commit B', when merging between user2(B') and dev(C) that line disappears. The same thing happens when we try to stash the changes before commit B' and merging with dev(C) and then reapplying the changes.

Is there a way to manually control what changes are being made during the merge so that we can merge only the changes we know we made?

Basically what we're currently forced to do is when we run across this issue we copy the changes to one side, create a new branch from dev, put the changes back and then merge those changes back into dev, but I know there's a saner way to do things.

```
Graph Log
* | | | | | | |   971fa0e Merge branch 'p' into 'dev'
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|/
|/| | | | | | |
| * | | | | | |   dcb98ea Merge branch 'dev' into 'p'
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \
| | | |_|_|_|_|/
| | |/| | | | |
| * | | | | | | d6fd278
| * | | | | | | 9d47bd7
| * | | | | | | 11560e7
| | |_|/ / / /
| |/| | | | |
* | | | | | | ace54f1
```

Comment: "The problem is that when we merge user2(B') into dev(C) it tends to override any changes made in commits B C"—there's no "it tends" about this.  The only way that happens is if someone is presented with the option to do that and chooses it, specifically and explicitly (edit: or simply orders a forcible override up front without even bothering to check).

Comment: Have to agree with @jthill here. If a merge has conflicting changes, it should show up as a merge conflict where the file is basically left containing *both* changes with special markers to indicate the source of each. It's up to the merging person to resolve those conflicts and commit the correct version.

Comment: Admittedly none of us are experienced with git, so what do you mean by being being presented with that option. We basically just do 
git dev pull
git checkout user2
git merge dev

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but without success. I however have an idea of what might have happened. Could you add to your question the relevant part of the output of `git log --graph  --oneline  --decorate`, you can remove the commit messages, just leave the messages of the merge commits please (so we know what has been mer.ged where

Comment: @padawin Done, a bit of a mess I know, we're still trying to find the best workflow for our team.

Comment: ok, is it the work from `ace54f1` which gets lost when the merge `971fa0e` occurs, or something else?

Comment: @padawin - If I'm reading this correctly, ace54f1 is where the two branches split. What's being lost is the changes made 11560e7, 9d47bd7 and d6fd278

Comment: Almost, `ace54f1` is just a commit of `dev`. `p` came from before that.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how your graph is (and that there seem to be a lot to come after that), I'd say the best for now would be to recreate a fresh branch `p` from `dev` and `git cherry-pick d6fd278 9d47bd7 11560e7` to get your commits back in the branch (plus any other commits you need in `p`).
You'd end up as follow:

```
* new commit for 11560e7 <p>
* new commit for 9d47bd7
* new commit for d6fd278
* <dev>
```

Then when the branch is ready to go in dev, you merge it:

```
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff p
```

And finally delete the branch `p`.

Comment: We've managed to undo the "damage" my question is more what we did wrong and how do we avoid doing it in the future?

Comment: It is hard to say, the rare cases when I've seen something similar was in cases of reverting changes. Would you be able to isolate and reproduce is a separate new repository to be able to see exactly what happened? Also, would it be possible to provide a larger log output, to have more context before and after? I guess the repository is not public, right?

I can't promise you anything, but I'll do my best to pinpoint it.